# FUSE hangs trying to mount network filesystem on login

Tags: linux, systemd, login, autofs, s3fs

I am using Fedora 23 and I have autofs set to automount some s3fs FUSE filesystems when directories under `/mnt/s3` are accessed. Since I set this up, I always experience an additional delay upon logging in - from looking at `journalctl`, it looks like something is immediately activating one of those s3fs filesystems as soon as I login - but this fails and times out because the wireless network connection is not yet up.

How can I find out what is causing this unwanted mounting, and/or disable it?

Comment: Have a look at the output of `lsof` perhaps?

Comment: @schaiba Unfortunately, `lsof` does not work in this case - it says: `lsof: warning: can't stat() fuse.s3fs file system /mnt/s3/example Output infomation may be incomplete`.

Comment: Sounds like something is being run when you log in, without seeing the contents of your login files, pam modules being loaded upon login etc etc then it is difficult to say. Also show the `journalctl` section that shows that something accessing the s3fs filesystem.